# Crashlytics integration issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, crash, crashlytics

I have trouble integrating **Crashlytics** into my project.

Having follow instruction on website. But soon after **installing the Crashlytics mac app**, add new build script, paste script, then I build my project to continue, then the app crashed.

**Update**: so back then, I forgot to initialize a Crashlytics instance in AppDelegate. It's totally my fault, not the service nor the client app (which is really really awesome by the way!). You can see answers below.

Comment: for you, whether it is working or not???

Comment: It's not working for me. After building project, there is a Crashlytics.framework in my project folder on disk.

Comment: from where can i download Crashlytics.framework. I couldnt find it in their website.

Comment: @Satyamsvv, you can download it from **[here](https://www.crashlytics.com/downloads/xcode)**. If the page is not visible, I think you have to login to Crashlytics dashboard.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the Build Phases of your target, click the + Add a Build Phase button in the bottom right and select Add Run Script. In the Crashlytics mac plugin, you should be given a run script to copy into this run script build phase. It will look like this:

```
./Crashlytics.framework/run <your api key>
```

Except your api key will be a 40 digit number provided by the plugin.

in your app delegate:

```
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` write the following line to start your Crashlytics session.

```
[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:<your api key>];
```

`<your api key>` is the same number in the run script.

Comment: I have 2 app project. I have set up for one.But same run script is giving error for another ./Crashlytics.framework/run: No such file or directory any idea?

Comment: @San you probably haven't linked the framework in the second project or it is not at the specified path. Make sure the framework exists in your project directory

Comment: What's build secret used for?

Comment: I assume things have been changed at the Crashlytics end but getting the Mac app automatically to formulate a script for me today gave `./Crashlytics.framework/run <40-digit api key> <64-digit some other key>`. I didn't immediately recognise the second key and for all I know it may be optional.

Comment: thanks I used this answer to understand how to clean crashlytics

Answer (score 7):

Crashlytics collect crashes only when app run NOT in debug mode.

Here is quote from Crashlytics Knowelege Base:
3. Then, make sure that a debugger is not connected.  By default, Xcode will launch applications and attach a debugger. This will prevent the crash from reporting -- detach it!

http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92522-is-there-a-quick-way-to-force-a-crash-

Comment: I wish I could also upvote your answer, but can't now. So I did select Debugger in Run scheme to None and force crash to test, it works fine now! :)

Answer (score 3):

Add Crashlytics framework in your Project and add your Crashlytics key in **Build Phase -> Run Script** as like in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the repsond! Sure, I did this with my key. But my problem here is when I build project to continue integration proccess, the Crashlytics client would crash and nothing would happen next. Tried to remove the app -> download new crashlytics.app -> repeat the process, but could not go any further

Answer (score 1):

Follow the advice in the answers above but in addition: IF you installed crashlytics via cocoapods, make sure you are using the proper path in your build phase script.

Use:

```
./Pods/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/run myLongKey
```

Instead Of:

```
./Crashlytics.framework/run myLongKey
```

Comment: I surprised this works. I have 3 apps with crashlytics + fabric installed via pods and only one of them is having this problem. I'm pretty sure my issue has something to do with derived data (still figuring it out)

Answer (score 0):

For me, there is something wrong with my Crashlytics.app Mac App. So i download one and reinstall it. then it works.