# Crashlytics - Build detected for target with API key xxx but we are expecting yyy (organisation...)

Tags: ios, crashlytics

Started seeing this error this morning. I can see the key in fabric dashboard and I understand why it complains. Not sure how to fix it.

Thoughts?

Comment: did you add  Run script under build phase ?

Comment: I did. I am not clear why I suddenly have a new key...

Comment: From the Mac app, click "Add new app" and build each target as a new app. Your API keys are organization, not app, specific. Unless you're adding another app to a different organization, you can use the same API key!

Comment: or try this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17687357/3901620

Comment: Simple: My code base is in Swift. Not sure if it is something with how I referred to it, Pods or other. Would have nice if you simply asked me to edit the question before down-voting. I took your point and edited the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here.

This usually means that the API key in your info.plist and run script build phase don't match for the app and Fabric organization. I'd double check the values you have against the values under your organization's name in your [Fabric settings](https://fabric.io/settings/organizations). Just click on "API key" and "Build secret" under the org's name after selecting your organization.